# Will iphone 5s convert text emoticons in SMS? Text emoticon for Rose emoji

Tags: iphone, sms

I don't have iphone myself and that is why I ask this question. Also I don't have a smartphone and don't think that my cellphone is able to send Unicode SMS.

I would like to know whether iphone 5s automatically converts text emoticons to emoji pictures in SMS. If it does, then what text emoticon will be converted to "Rose emoji" (http://emojipedia.org/rose/).

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons)
lists several strings for Rose:

- @};-
- @}->--
- @}‑;‑'‑‑‑
- @>‑‑>‑‑

Will one of this strings be converted to "Rose emoji" if sent via SMS to Iphone 5s?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these are converted for me by my iPhone on iOS 9.3.3.

Comment: Some text emoticons are automatically converted in SMS on iPhone 5s. There may be other text emoticons not included in OP that will be converted to "Rose emoji". Is my understanding of your answer correct?